# Error whenever trying to create an order in Magento 2.3.3: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage

Tags: orders, magento2.3.3, order-email

The error seems to originate from trying to create an Email when a new order is created, the weird thing however is that Email's is turned off for the store.

From what i know of nothing has changed and the error suddenly appeared after 3 months of Magento running completely fine.

I have tried applying the patch **EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch for Magento 2.3.3**.

The error that appears in the system.log is the following:

```
[2021-02-12 07:41:49] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage, Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []

[2021-02-12 07:41:49] main.CRITICAL: Saving order 5000279516 failed: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage [] []\n
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The issue is resolved. It was due to an error produced by an extension.